# Using JSON to store static data and build elements acceptable?

Tags: php, json

I'm currently building my first real web app using php and have a question about how I've been storing static data.

In an attempt to try and keep my code clean I've been storing data in JSON files locally and built a File class which fetches the data as and when needed. For example I have an acronyms page and for this it seems a perfectly reasonable.

I've also been using the same method to build simple forms using a JSON file that contains input types, labels, names etc. it's actually working really well of I'm honest.

My question is, is this an ok practice to use or am I just performing a faux pas that shouldn't be done? I want to try and do everything an acceptable way as I'm hoping to move into software development professionally at some point and don't want to develop any bad habits.

Thanks.

Comment: its fine to use static or dynamic json, almost everyone does it, mocking, headless apis, its somewhat more popular in the nodejs world. your issue will come when you no longer want the fs overhead or locking issues with multiple users or are needing to do complex querys and joins etc

Comment: tip: this type of question is better suited for [code review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Hopefully that shouldn't be an issue. I'm using a database to store user info, company info etc. The JSON files are just used to store static information for static pages and the original idea was to try and keep my controllers clean without huge arrays that were used to build forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is totally fine to use a JSON file to store some informations. On the other side since, on a real software scenario, you will work with many information all related to each other (ex. Users, Accounts, Privileges, etc.) it is pretty difficult to manage them in a simple JSON file. That's why a database solution come in place (sql or noSql) to help relating data, retrieve, store etc, in a safer more efficient and data not corrupted way. Hope I have been clear enough.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm using a database for user accounts etc. I've not been using JSON for anything important like that.

Mostly I've been using JSON files for storing data to use to build a simple form. I originally had this in an array within my controller but thought it looked a lot cleaner in a separate file.

As for the acronyms etc. I wrote a script in python to extract them from a spreadsheet and it seemed easiest to store them in JSON. With the same thinking if the spreadsheet is ever updated then I can use it to fetch an updated list quite easily.

Comment: I totally agree

Comment: Thanks again for the help :)